# Training on Sagemaker GPU is too slow

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I've launched a training on CelebA dataset for a binary classification with PyTorch, in Sagemaker Studio.

I've made sure all, model, tensors are sent to cuda().

My image dataset is in S3, and I'm accessing it via this import and code:

```
from PIL import Image
import s3fs

fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

# example
f = fs.open(f's3://aoha-bucket/img_celeba/dataset/000001.jpg')
```

And of course my PyTorch DataLoader class, which is using of s3fs to load data into DataLoaders.

```
class myDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, target, length, adv = None, transform=None):
        self.annotations = pd.read_csv(csv_file).iloc[:length,:]
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.target = target
        self.length = length
        self.adv = adv

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.annotations)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img_path = fs.open(os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.annotations.loc[index, 'image_id']))
        image = Image.open(img_path)
        image = np.array(image)

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image=image)["image"]

        image = np.transpose(image, (2, 0, 1)).astype(np.float32)
        image = torch.Tensor(image)

        y_label = torch.tensor(int(self.annotations.loc[index, str(self.target)]))

        if self.adv is None:
            return image, y_label

        if self.adv :
            z_label = torch.tensor(int(self.annotations.loc[index, 'origin']))
            return image, y_label, z_label
```

when I run this function, I get True:

```
next(model.parameters()).is_cuda
```

My issue is that, I don't know the training is too slow, even slower than my local CPU (not that powerful). It says for example, that one epoch is needing 1h45minutes, which is way too much.

Im' using a GPU optimized PyTorch instance of Studio.

Have you ever launched a training on GPU in Sagemaker using PyTorch ?
Could you please help ?

Thank you very much,
Habib

Comment: I have no experience with pytorch, but I use sagemaker. What instance type are you using? Maybe it's just to cheap (not powerful enough) ..

Comment: Hello rok;thank you for your reply. I'm using Tesla T4 from Sagemaker Studio. It has 15Go of memory, I guess enough for my 100000 dataset images. But too slow. I use the same code, but wrapping it inside PyTorch of sagemaker.pytorch (not local mode), it runs fast ! which implies that it uses the GPU of the instance I'm launching. I've been struggling with this since 2 weeks :/. Thank you for your help.

Comment: And last question, if you've already experienced keras in sagemaker, do you use flow_from_directory method or another technique to load data from S3 ? I feel flow_from_directory might cause a bottleneck...

Comment: I always used file mode, so data fully replicated in the instance. Data is entirely downloaded from S3 to the instance..